# Why doesn't my UICollectionView scroll when I drag the blank space in between the items?

Tags: cocoa-touch, scroll, uicollectionview

I'm creating a grid layout with `UICollectionView`, but the scrolling only seems to work if I press down on an image. If I press down on the blank space, the view doesn't scroll. How do I enable scrolling for presses that are both on the background and on the images?

For example, in the screenshot below, scrolling only works if I press down on the white squares, but not if I press down on the black between the squares.

[image]

I don't think I have any scrolling specific code, but if you'd like me to add specific code samples let me know.

Comment: Same issue here, and Answer 1 did not work

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `backgroundColor` or `backgroundView` of your `UICollectionView`, it will scroll when touched anywhere within the view (including between the white squares in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this issue. Here is what I did:

I noticed the problem was my UICollectionViewCell had userInteractionEnabled = YES. I tried to change this value to NO, and scroll started to work. The UICollectionViewCells were intercepting the touch and Collection view scroll didn't work.

But I had a collateral problem: once I touched a cell, didSelectItemAtIndexPath method didn't get called.

My solution is add a UITapGestureRecognizer to detect if a cell has been touched and call this method manually.

Add this to viewDidLoad method:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

And here is the singleTapGestureCaptured method:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:touchPoint];
    [self collectionView:self.collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Hope this help you!